# How to best handle pointermove and click event on mobiles for OpenLayers?

Tags: hover, tooltip, openlayers, addeventlistener, openlayers-6

As can be seen [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=pointermove), the `pointermove` event cannot be used on iOS Safari, which is the most used browser of my target users. On an OpenLayers map, I'd like to show a tooltip when hovering on specific layers' feature. It works well on desktop with `pointermove`, but what's the best practice to include a similar behavior for mobiles? I'd like some guidance before I do too much in the wrong direction

- Should I then listen to the `click` or `singleclick` event as well, to include mobiles?
- If so, should I just add two listeners and refer to the same callback?
- If so, should I check which device triggers the event, to avoid (possible?) weird behavior?
- I am not sure of the tolerance on mobile devices for clicks: should I use the `hitTolerance` option of `forEachFeatureAtPixel`, and would I then need to programmatically make sure that I'm getting the feature closest to the clicked pixel and not some random one within the tolerance area?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Now all major browsers support Pointer events natively and Openlayers removed [Pointer polyfill since v6.4](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.0). If you are targeting older browsers that do not support Pointer events, you now need to include a pointer events polyfill ([elm-pep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-pep) or [pepjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openlayers/pepjs)) in your application. You'll then can use `pointermove` events on all platforms.

Comment: Merci @Jean-Marc to have looked at my question. Unfortunately your answer is not a solution. I've found out that iOS Safari is now modernized and is compatible with Pointer events. But, being a touch device, it emits `pointermove` only when the map is panned, as explained in [Openlayers doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapBrowserEvent-MapBrowserEvent.html). This is indeed not the behavior that I'm looking for. I ended up listening to different events, namely `pointermove` on desktop and `pointerup` ('click' also works) on mobile, with a device check.